# Is there any other plugin available in groovy that supports spring security for the implementation of User Roles and Permission?

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy

I wanted to know if there are still available plugins compatible with groovy that work fine with the `spring security core plugin` for the implementation of `User Roles and Permissions`. I have tried using the `ACL plugin`, but it doesn't satisfy the requirements. What is going on with ACL is that, every permission is assigned to a specific user. What I wanted to do is to assign permissions to role, then role to permission.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `aclUtilService.addPermission()` the second arg is the recipient. It's either a username or a role (the logic in the service is pretty simple - it just checks the string to see if it starts with "ROLE_"). If it's a role, then the permission is granted to the role, and so any user with that role.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be the spring security core plugin? The Shiro plugin supports roles and permissions as well and might be a good fit in your situation.

http://grails.org/plugin/shiro

Comment: yes i need to configure the user roles and permission using the spring security plugin..